# Create a tag from a previous tag

Tags: git

I’m trying to create a tag from a tag in my repo.

I have the following tags:

```
4.0
3.1
3.0
```

I’m trying to roll back to 3.1 and add a minor change and then create 3.2 and had that available.

I’ve reset the head back to 3.1 `git reset —hard 3.1` and added my small changes.

I’ve then created my tag 3.2 added and committed and tried to push.

My push was rejected due to :  “**Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart**.”

So i’ve pulled, and this has pulled down 4.0 which consists of breaking changes compared to 3.1

Is there anyway I can push up 3.2 which is a slightly amended 3.1 and not have to merge in 4.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conflict probably occured because of the reset of your current branch and has nothing to do with the tags, the following procedure should work:

```
git checkout 3.1
git checkout -b 3.1-hotfix
git add a b c
git commit
git tag 3.2
```

See this image of the history of an example repository. Note that the `3.2` tag was created after the `4.0` one using the method above!

[image: Resulting history]

If the `3.2` changes are relevant for 4.0 as well simply merge them in:

```
git checkout master
# --no-ff is good style as it does not fast farword and makes merges more obvious
git merge --no-ff 3.2
```

[image: Resulting history after merge]